# HTML5 Video in WebView Android Ver 4+?

Tags: android, html, video, cordova, webview

As far as I've read you cannot show a video through the HTML5 video tag in a WebView on Android OS 3. But is there anyone who have done this on the latest version of the OS (4+)?

I'm currently developing an android application with HTML5 and PhoneGap and would like to embed videos directly on the pages of the app.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it would not be a problem. I have developed a PhoneGap application for 4.1 Android based tablet that shows video with HTML5  tag with no problem (the movies are mp4 container with H264 video and AAC audio streams). Although you need to manually play the video and if you want looping, you should do it manually as well.

Comment: could you elaborate? I cannot get mine to play. What is the path to you video? is a relative path like media/vieos/video.mp4 ?

Comment: The path is an absolute path of the video file, for example file:///sdcard/movie.mp4. I am playing video dymamically, so my code in js file is something like: $('#eventVideoControl').attr('src', videoClipFilename);
$('#eventVideoControl').fadeIn();
var video = $('#eventVideoControl').get(0);
video.load();
// Android does not support looping, so do it manually
video.loop = false; 
video.addEventListener('ended', function() {
video.currentTime=0.0; video.play(); }, false);
video.play();